# jQuery validate only validates one field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validate to validate a form. I have two text boxes on my form and only the first one will add the "This field is required." message. If I remove the "required" class from the first one the second will have the message.

html:

```
<form id="questionForm">
<div><input class="required" id="value" type="text" /></div>
<div><textarea class="required" id="description"></textarea></div>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$("#questionForm").validate({ submitHandler: function() { 
        alert("valid");
    } 
});
```

Why is only one being validated?

Edit: I'm using jQuery validation plug-in 1.7

- http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
- http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Edit 2: I'm using MVC 3

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I just ran into this issue myself.  Pulled my hair out for an hour, but here it is:

Throw the "name" attribute in there as well and that may do the trick.

Comment: Into your input fields I mean. :)

Comment: Dude thanks! almost smashed my head againts the keyboard because of this.

Comment: Spent an hour debugging my form for just a simple problem! I was about to burn my eyebrows from inspecting every letter of my code! Thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks brilliant, I would have wasted hours trying to read through the documentation had I not have found this

Comment: Thanks a tonne. Was at it for a day before seeing this answer.

Comment: dude thank you so much. I was minutes away from setting myself on fire and jumping out of my 5th story window

Comment: This is really annoying because in a credit card processing situation I'm specifically looking to not have name tags on our inputs.

Comment: Dynamically generated UI with dynamically generated validation objects.  I was sure there was something wrong with the validation.  I never thought to check for the name attributes.  They were missing on all dynamic fields.  : ( Two days of troubleshooting all the wrong things...  Five minutes on Stack and it's solved.  Thanks @Jay

Comment: thank you thank you thank you , I was spending a whole day without this name attribute :(((((((((((((((((((

Comment: This is why I love Stack Overflow. I was about to spend countless time on something I found and resolved in minutes because of SO. Thank you!

Comment: I was banging my head against my keyboard all day.  I use expensive mechanical keyboards, too!  After I broke about 7 $100 keyboards with my forehead, I finally found your answer here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to enter the `name` attribute for every DOM element which you want to validate using the  `Jquery.validate()` function .

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what validation plugin you are using, it is difficult to nail down the problem. However, it seems as though jQuery isn't loop through each of the fields, but it stops when it reaches in an invalid field. Try using the jQuery `$.each()` method, and using some conditionals to make sure the validation process does not stop when the validator reaches an invalid field.

Hope that helps,
spryno724

Answer (score 1):

I think the alert is blocking the validation of both fields. After 1 alert the rest of the javascript stops. What happens if you use `$('#questionForm').validate();` instead?

Comment: Nope that isn't it. I tried your suggestion and also removed the alert() and it didn't work. I thought the submit handler was a call back function so it won't get called until the form is validated.

Comment: I'm not sure either, but I faced the problem more then once that a loop was stopped by an alert. Not sure why since it shouldn't return anything.

Comment: and what I get from the documentation you're right: it seems it should be called when the form is validated (by default it's just `form.submit();`

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you added **name** property in your required field

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#basic-form").validate({
  // comment it out if you want to hide error messgae below inputfield
    /*errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      return true;
    }*/
  // Call once form is valid
  submitHandler: function (form) {
    alert('Done');
  }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  width: 300px;
}

form, p {
  margin: 20px;
}

p.note {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: red;
}

input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

label {
  width: 300px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

label span {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

label.error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

input.error {
    border: 1px dashed red;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: red;
}

[type="submit"], [type="reset"], button, html [type="button"] {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 10px 0;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<form id="basic-form" action="" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input id="name" name="name" minlength="3" type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="email">E-Mail <span>(required)</span></label>
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </p>
</form>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>

</body>
```