# How to fix the case with jQuery Validate - only one field is validated?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 fields in my (simplified) form. And I use jQuery Validate plugin to validate both of them, but only one field is validated - see [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/LFHB9/).

What can be wrong here? How to validate both fields?

(there is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971392/jquery-validate-only-validates-one-field), but there is no solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is in fact being performed for both fields - you're just not getting an error message. If you do an inspect element (using Chromium, or Firefox with Firebug), you'll see the input tag will have a class `error`.

You're missing the `<span></span>` at the end of the `div` surrounding the `last_name` input field. Add that empty span, and you'll see the error message come up.

Answer (score 1):

Your `errorPlacement` code is broken. If you remove that, you can see that both fields are validated correctly. You only have one `<span>` in your html so `.find("span"));` finds that and reports both errors in the same element..