# How to display an error message for only focused field?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net

I have 2 TextBox ; tb1 and tb2 .on load , focus is on tb1 .. on save button tb1 and tb2 are empty ... i want to show only tb1 error messege ...

this is my code

```
$('#btn_SaveCategory').click(function () {

                var uname = $('#txt_CategoryName').val();
                var Description = $('#txt_CategoryDesc').val();

                if (uname == '') {
                    alert("Please Enter Category Name");
                    $('#txt_CategoryName').focus();
                }

                if (Description == '') {
                    alert("Please Enter Category Description");
                }


            });
```

I Tried to search but found a link who is opposite
:[jQuery validate only validates one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971392/jquery-validate-only-validates-one-field)

please suggest if i am missing something

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/7LRCs/

```
$('#btn_SaveCategory').click(function () {
    var uname = $('#txt_CategoryName').val();
    var Description = $('#txt_CategoryDesc').val();

    if (uname == '') {
        alert("Please Enter Category Name");
        $('#txt_CategoryName').focus();
    }
    else if (Description == '') {
        alert("Please Enter Category Description");
        $('#txt_CategoryDesc').focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `if else if` like this

```
$('#btn_SaveCategory').click(function () {
  var uname = $('#txt_CategoryName').val();
  var Description = $('#txt_CategoryDesc').val();

  if (uname == '') {
     alert("Please Enter Category Name");
     $('#txt_CategoryName').focus();
  }
  else if (Description == '') {
     alert("Please Enter Category Description");
     $('#txt_CategoryDesc').focus();
  }
});
```

or you can `return` the function before checking next condition. Like this

```
$('#btn_SaveCategory').click(function () {

    var uname = $('#txt_CategoryName').val();
    var Description = $('#txt_CategoryDesc').val();
    if (uname == '') {
       alert("Please Enter Category Name");
        $('#txt_CategoryName').focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (Description == '') {
       alert("Please Enter Category Description");
       $('#txt_CategoryDesc').focus();
       return false;
    }

});
```